# Replace only one XML attribute with Structural Replace

Tags: xml, android-studio, intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to replace attributes `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"` with `android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"` in all TextView tags.

So I tried to use Structural Replace with search template:

```
<TextView android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>
```

and replacement template:

```
<TextView android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"/>
```

[image]

Search works fine, but replace wipes out all other attributes from TextView tag:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

is replaced by

```
<TextView android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"/>
```

How to modify replacement template to change only fontFamily tag?

Answer (score 3):

Currently I can only suggest catching all extra parameters in a metavariable and reusing it in the replace template.

Use the following as search template:

```
<TextView android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" $attrs$/>
```

the following as a replacement template:

```
<TextView android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium" $attrs$/>
```

and click on the "Edit Variables" button, then choose `attr` on the left and make sure that its minimal count is zero and maximal count is unlimited (it's done by checking the checkbox in 2018.1.4, and by removing maximal count altogether in EAP).

If you want to preserve inner elements (hardly applicable to `TextView`), you can use the same trick.

The main problem is that order of attributes is not preserved: `fontFamily` will become first. That can also be solved, but that's a different trick.